# Enide Studio 2014 can't be used

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse, enide

Enide Studio 2014 based on preview of Eclipse 4.4 M4 Luna

new ->Node.js project .

hello-world-server.njs is  this：

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

1 question:why hello-world-server.njs  is  not  hello-world-server.js.

What is the difference between JS and NJS

2 question： Im runing  node Application

```
     Console show：
    org.nodeclipse.debug.launch.LaunchShortcut
    node E:\work\node_eclipse_w\k\hello-world-server.njs --tea-pot-mode
```

but  I can't    Visit the page  “127.0.0.1:1337”

end：thank  you。

Answer (score 0):

Read updated intro http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/studio/2014/

in short you you need to install Enide Studio 2014 plugins (v0.17) into recent Eclipse. 
Now you are using old v0.11 of Nodeclipse

You also can update Eclipse and Nodeclipse (that makes Enide Studio 2014) to the latest versions.